# Restart system if it runs out of memory?

Tags: linux, reboot, out-of-memory

I need to run some memory heavy tests in a remote computer through SSH. Last time I did this, the computer stopped responding, and it was necessary for someone to physically reboot it.

Is there a way I can set it up so that the system restarts instead of freezing if too much memory is being used? (I do have root access). The kernel version is 4.9.0.

Comment: Schedule a reboot with `at`, run your tests, cancel the `at` command if you're still connected; or wait for the reboot if you aren't.  Old sysadmin trick.

Comment: Or see if there is some sort of watchdog support in the BIOS in the event Linux is really failing about and does need to be poked.

Comment: Do you have any `/dev/watchdog*` devices?

Comment: @SatoKatsura if the system really has become unresponsive who's to say your `at` job could even be started?

Comment: @roaima If the system (presumed to be Linux) has become unresponsive as a result of running out of memory, then OOM is already "committing random acts of terrorism", as DJB used to put it.  Then `at` is just as likely to be left alive to do its job as any other recovery method.  There's always a chance of getting stuck.  In order to avoid OOM going on a rampage one needs either a hardware watchdog (which is rarely found on consumer motherboards), or setting sane limits.  But setting limits doesn't seems to be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To monitor/recover the control of a "unstable"/starver server, I would advise to use an hardware, or failing that a software watchdog; in Debian you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install watchdog
```

Then you edit `/etc/watchdog.conf` and add thresholds or tests; from the top of my head, the watchdog is also activated as such that if the kernel does not see it for a good while it reboots. e.g. if a software routine does not talk in a fixed time with `/dev/watchdog0` or something similar.

For instance, you can define load thresholds in `/etc/watchdog.conf`:

```
max-load-1             = 40
max-load-5             = 18
max-load-15            = 12
```

Be aware also that some boards/chipsets come with built-in watchdogs; if I am not wrong the Arm A20 is one of them.

From [man watchdog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog)

> The Linux kernel can reset the system if serious problems are
>   detected. This can be implemented via special watchdog hardware, or
>   via a slightly less reliable software-only watchdog inside the kernel.
>   Either way, there needs to be a daemon that tells the kernel the
>   system is working fine. If the daemon stops doing that, the system is
>   reset.
>
> watchdog is such a daemon. It opens /dev/watchdog, and keeps writing to
>   it often enough to keep the kernel from resetting, at least once per
>   minute. Each write delays the reboot time another minute. After a
>   minute of inactivity the watchdog hardware will cause the reset. In
>   the case of the software watchdog the ability to reboot will depend on
>   the state of the machines and interrupts.
>
> The watchdog daemon can be stopped without causing a reboot if the
>   device /dev/watchdog is closed correctly, unless your kernel is
>   compiled with the CONFIG_WATCHDOG_NOWAYOUT option enabled.

see also [Raspberry Pi and Arduino: Building Reliable Systems With WatchDog Timers](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-and-Arduino-Building-Reliable-Systems/)

Comment: I tried this but still got a frozen computer that didn't reboot.

Comment: @user7000 It is a stress situation and many things can go wrong. It wont work 100% of the time. Also there are hardware watchdogs you can buy.

Comment: Yeah I've not seen good reviews for any hardware watchdog but I would like to get one.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific question, you can set sysctls like:

```
vm.panic_on_oom=1
kernel.panic=10
```

so that the kernel will panic if the system runs out of memory and then reboot after ten seconds of panicking.

On new systems with full cgroups2 support, systemd-oomd may be a less drastic option.